# Error to create matrix with zeros in kotlin using Mat.zeros

Tags: java, android, opencv, kotlin, mobile

I'm working on developing an application using opencv. I'm uploading an image and assigning a new matrix with the same size as the original image, but in this matrix I need to fill all the rows and columns with 0. However, the function Mat.zeros is not assigning 0 in my matrix and I have the output filled with values: [D @ 13a5b9d, [D @ f3978b1, [D @ 30c17d0 ...
Oh, and I need it to be a matrix of type Mat () because I will work with opencv. Can someone help me solve this error
Code:

```
val srcOriginal = Imgcodecs.imread(currentPhotoPath)

val markers = Mat.zeros(srcOriginal.rows(), srcOriginal.cols(), CvType.CV_32S)

for(x in 0..markers.rows()) {
   for(y in 0..markers.cols()) {
      Log.i("teste", markers[x,y])
  }
}
```

Output expected:

```
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
...
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually creates a matrix filled with the correct values. The thing is, `markers[x,y]` returns a value of type `DoubleArray`, not `Double` and hence you cannot see the actual content. If you print the values with the following line you will see that there are zeros in the matrix:

```kotlin
Log.i("teste", markers[x,y].contentToString())

// Alternative using the Java Arrays class
Log.i("teste", Arrays.toString(markers[x,y]))
```